# mssql connect to state

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

Hey Everyone hope all ok. I am needing your expertise.

I have an html form and inside of it i have a drop down option to choose a state

```
<select name="State">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
       etc.....
</select>
```

Any-time the customer selects a a state and submits the form it goes to my mssql database and pulls an ip address releavant to the staten they choose in the html form.

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| stateip_id| state |   user_ip     |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
|      1    | AL    | 67.100.244.74 |
|      2    | AK    | 68.20.131.135 |
|      3    | AZ    | 64.134.225.33 |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
```

So for example, lets say they choose Alabama (AL), when they submit the form i want the code to connect to the php file and then show the ip address releavant to the state, in this case (AL). For each state i have 200 different ip addresses, so i want it to randomly choose and ip for the state choosen.

I found some php code and have tested it with my details and it is connecting to the database fine.

```
<?php
$Server = "00.00.000.000,0000";
$User = "username";
$Pass = "password";
$DB = "dbname";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($Server, $User, $Pass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $Server"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($DB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $DB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT stateip_id, state, user_ip ";
$query .= "FROM state_ip ";
$query .= "WHERE state='AK'"; 

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 

//display the results 
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["stateip_id"] . $row["state"] . $row["user_ip"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

The problem i have is the WHERE part

```
$query .= "WHERE state='AK'";
```

If i do like i have above and add a AK, or AL in the ' ' section it displays all ip address that are associated with AL or AK. What i want it to do is recognise the state choosen from the form and then only display one ip address randomly choosen according to the state

I am just not sure what to add to that WHERE state='what in here'"; part to make it all work and have it randomly select an ip from the state

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$state = $_POST['State'];

$query = "SELECT TOP 1 stateip_id, state, user_ip
              FROM state_ip
              WHERE state='$state'
              ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is working and picking up the correct ip address, the only thing it is not doing is picking up a random one everytime, is there something else i need to add. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean, you can use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 stateip_id, state, user_ip
FROM state_ip
WHERE state='THE-CHOOSEN-STATE'
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Please, note the use of the RAND() function (to randomly order the retrieved rows) and the use of TOP 1 (to retrieve just one row).